# Close outlook task in open event

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to open an outlook task and trigger a new journal entry.
After this I want to close this task.
I used the objTask.Close in the objTask_Open event but this gives me the following error: Argument not optional.
Is it possible to close a task in its own event function after opening ?

Best regards,

Wamor

```
Public WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Public WithEvents objJournal As Outlook.JournalItem
Public WithEvents objTask As Outlook.TaskItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInspectors = Outlook.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is TaskItem Then
       Set objTask = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is JournalItem Then
       Set objJournal = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub objTask_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Create journal item
    Set objMyFolder = GetFolder("Archive Folders\Archive Folders")
    Set objJournal = objMyFolder.Items.Add(olJournalItem)

    'Fill journal with task-information
    With objJournal
        .StartTimer
        ' Retrieve the PST-file where the task is located.
        .Categories = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Parent
        .Type = "Note"
        .Subject = objTask.Subject
        .Display
    End With
    objTask.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates "Argument not optional."

The syntax is expression.Close(SaveMode) where the argument, SaveMode, is required.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/taskitem-close-method-outlook

Choose from olDiscard or olPromptForSave or olSave.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/olinspectorclose-enumeration-outlook